# Count the occurrences of duplicate values among columns of a table

Tags: sql, duplicates

I've a table where each column contains integers and some values are duplicates.
Here the example:

```
| ColumnA    | Column B    | Column C |
|       2    |        3    |        1 |     
|       1    |        1    |        3 |   
|       2    |        1    |        3 |
```

How can I do a SQL query in order to count the occurrences of each integer?
I want to obtain something like that:
the count for 2 is 2, the count for 1 is 4, the count for 3 is 3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this:

```
SELECT Col, COUNT(*) AS TOT
FROM (
    SELECT ColumnA AS Col FROM table
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ColumnB FROM table
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ColumnC FROM table
) AS A
GROUP BY Col
```